# Graphics drawing image backgammon game

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

this is probably going to be a silly question but i am only a beginner so mercy on my soul :).
so my problem is that i have a class called game page which is the IFrame that displays the all game.
inside it i got a class called Board which contains a pic of the board which paints itself just fine using:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
  super.paintComponent(page);
  page.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

image is the image of the board i get it like this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/board.png"));
```

ok that works fine.
so inside the board i also got a 2d Array of the type "Slot", Slot is another class i wrote that got a Stack of WhitePiece or Stack of BlackPiece
those are classes i wrote representing the black or white pieces on the board.

so in the Board class there is a method called reset board which organizes it to the start position of backgammon so it intisialize all the slots.

now the Black and White pieces got a pic inside of the type Image which i get like this:
    pic = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/whitePiece.png"));

now the problem is when inside reset board i call the drawSlot method from the Slot class
it cant get the pic i think.
i call it like this:
first i call drawBoard:
      drawBoard(board);

then here is drawBoard:

```
  public void drawBoard(Slot[][] board) throws IOException{
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<12;j++){
        board[i][j].drawSlot(getGraphics());
    }
   }
  }
```

and here is the problemtic method: drawSlot:

```
  public void drawSlot(Graphics g) throws IOException{    
  if(type == SlotType.empty){ 
      System.out.println("no type selected slot is empty Slot  Number"+slotNumber);
  }else
      if(type == SlotType.white){
        if(!wPieces.isEmpty()){
        Image pic = wPieces.pop().getPic();
        wPieces.push(new WhitePiece());
        if(slotNumber <= 11){
          for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
            g.drawImage(pic, 5, i*30, null);
          }
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                g.drawImage(pic, 5,300-(i*30), null);
            }
       }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Slot Stack is Empty Slot #"+slotNumber);
        }
      }else
      {
          if(!bPieces.isEmpty()){
          Image pic = bPieces.pop().getPic();
          bPieces.push(new BlackPiece());
          if(slotNumber<=11){
             for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                g.drawImage(pic, 5, i*30, 30, 30, null);
            }
          }else{
              for(int i=0;i<piecesAmount;i++){
                    g.drawImage(pic, 5, 300-(i*30), 30, 30, null);
              }  
          }
    }
          else{
      System.out.println("Slot Stack is empty Slot #"+slotNumber);
   }
}

 }
```

and here is the eror i get: (i think it indicates the way i get the pic isnt good.)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Try1.Slot.drawSlot(Slot.java:122)
at Try1.Board.drawBoard(Board.java:128)
at Try1.Board.resetBoard(Board.java:122)
at Try1.GamePage.<init>(GamePage.java:98)
at Try1.StartPage.startGame(StartPage.java:67)
at Try1.StartPage$eventHandler.actionPerformed(StartPage.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i would love to know what i did wrong.
thanks you all i know its a long post and you really have to get into it 
but i am a beginner and in need of help :).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 4) As already mentioned, don't call `getGraphics()` on components.  5)  Change `g.drawImage(pic, 5, i*30, null);` to `g.drawImage(pic, 5, i*30, this);` for all image drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `getGraphics()` on swing components. Draw the slots in `paintComponent()`.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    page.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    drawBoard(page, board);
}
```

And modify drawBoard() to use the passed graphics object:

```
public void drawBoard(Graphics g, Slot[][] board) {
   for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<12;j++){
           board[i][j].drawSlot(g);
       }
   }
}
```

And then call `repaint()` when the board changes.

Comment: @GiladBenYe I updated the answer a bit to pass graphics properly to `drawBoard()`

Comment: ok things are starting to get better in my app
i still have to work on positioning.